# Getting a pid of a process created in C#

Tags: c#, process, pid

Lets say that I'm trying to create a new process with the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
p.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\AwesomeFile.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "parameter1 parameter2";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
```

and right in the next line, I'll try to get a pid of that process with the following line:

```
MessageBox.Show(p.Id);
```

This line is giving me the "No process is associated with this object." error. Any idea as to why this error occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("processname")[0].Id.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

Is there a way to identify different processes of the same name? Lets say that I have two iexplore processes running, both were initially executed with different urls as parameters. How would I know which one is which in the array?

Comment: I noticed this command:

System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("processname")[0].StartInfo

which includes argument parameter, which would be great, but it turns out to be empty on a file that was not executed by C#. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 10):

Check the return value of [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx).  In some cases, Process.Start can return false, in which case no Id will be associated with it.