# How to get PID of the certain chromedriver in c# - there are multiple instances

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pid

Due to an annoying bug that exists in selenium : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4054

I need to kill the chromdriver.exe manually. However, i wonder that are there anyway i can get the PID of the existing chrome driver?

I am using windows 8.1

Other components

- Selenium.Support 3.4.0
- Selenium.WebDriver 3.4.0
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 2.29.0
- c# .net 4.6.2
- Microsoft Visual   Studio Community 2017 RC

To clarify, there are multiple instances and i want to get only certain instance PID

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill some processes by .exe file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345363/kill-some-processes-by-exe-file-name)

Comment: There are a number of questions already answered on killing processes by name, getting various details etc.

Comment: @BugFinder i have multiple instances of same exe

Comment: OK did you start the exe or did something else?

Comment: @BugFinder  something else starts. this command :             ChromeDriver cdDrive = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Sure you dont just want to use cdDrive.Close(); cdDrive.Quit(); ?

Comment: @BugFinder sure i would like to use them. but due to an annoying bug in selenium they dont work under certain circumstances : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4054

Comment: I am searching for something similar.  when I launch a new chromedriver I would like to have its process ID or be able to pass in an argument which identifies it  Then I would know which one to kill later on.

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use answer from this link [Getting a pid of a process created in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539920/getting-a-pid-of-a-process-created-in-c-sharp)

as it was stated where
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("chromdriver.exe")[0].Id

will return PID number

Comment: but there are multiple instances

Comment: are u have several **chromdriver.exe** processes in memory?

Comment: yep i have since i run multiple individual instances